# Xamarin.Forms: User Interface working properly in UWP but not on the Android Part

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, uwp-xaml

Good Day Everyone. I'm currently working on a simple program that enables the user to CRUD record of an Employee.

I was able to retrieve the created data from ASP.NET Web application and display it on the UWP part of my program. However, it's not working PROPERLY on whenever i run it on Android. Meaning, some Menu and Buttons are not being displayed.

I code all of this in the Xamarin.Forms Portable.

Here is the code of my Menu page that should be displayed properly on both platform. If you want to see more codes, just please let me know. Thanks a lot.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="XamarinFormsDemo.Views.MenuPage"
         BackgroundImage="bg3.jpg">


  <StackLayout>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"
             Padding="30"
             HeightRequest="30"
             BackgroundColor="#24e97d">
      <Image Source="ebmspersonnellogo1.png"
         HeightRequest="40"/>
    </StackLayout>


    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"
             VerticalOptions="Center"
      Padding="45,60,45,60">


      <Image x:Name="sales"
              Source="salesicon.png">

              <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer

                        Tapped="SalesTapGestureRecognizer_OnTapped"
                        NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
              </Image.GestureRecognizers>
        </Image>

      <Image x:Name="personnel"
        Source="personnelicon.png">

        <Image.GestureRecognizers>
          <TapGestureRecognizer

              Tapped="PersonnelTapGestureRecognizer_OnTapped"
              NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
        </Image.GestureRecognizers>
      </Image>



  <Image x:Name="crm"
    Source="crmicon.png">

    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
      <TapGestureRecognizer

              Tapped="CRMTapGestureRecognizer_OnTapped"
              NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
  </Image>



  <Image x:Name="asset"
    Source="asseticon.png">
    <Image.GestureRecognizers>

      <TapGestureRecognizer

              Tapped="AssetTapGestureRecognizer_OnTapped"
              NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
  </Image>

  <Image x:Name="receivables"
    Source="receivables.png">

    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
      <TapGestureRecognizer

              Tapped="ReceivablesTapGestureRecognizer_OnTapped"
              NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
  </Image>






  <Image x:Name="prapprovals"
    Source="prapprovals.png">

    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
      <TapGestureRecognizer

              Tapped="ApprovalsTapGestureRecognizer_OnTapped"
              NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
        </Image.GestureRecognizers>
      </Image>


    </StackLayout>


    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"
             Padding="30,10,30,10"
             HeightRequest="20"
             BackgroundColor="#24e97d"
             VerticalOptions="Center"
             Opacity="0.5">
      <Label Text="© Copyright 2015   smesoft.com.ph   All Rights Reserved " 
         HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
         VerticalOptions="Center" 
         HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    </StackLayout>



  </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Here are the Screenshots of 1.) **UWP** and 2.) **Android.**

[image: UWP]

[image]

Comment: Can you please show a screenshot of UWP vs Android so we can get a clear picture of what the difference is.

Comment: @AdamPedley Oh sorry. I've added the screenshots Sir.

Answer (score 0):

You can use grid instead of StackLayout. That would be best fit in current scenario.

For Example:-

```
<Grid>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

<Image x:Name="sales" Source="SomeTime1.png" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="SalesTapGestureRecognizer_OnTapped" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
</Image>

<Image x:Name="sales" Source="SomeTime2.png" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="PersonnelTapGestureRecognizer_OnTapped" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
</Image>

...
```